# How can I change my workspace switcher in Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, workspaces, cinnamon

In Cinnamon, you can move your pointer to the top left corner of the screen to activate the desktop switcher.  This would be awesome...if I wasn't left-handed.  I throw the pointer up there most of the time.  It's massively frustrating.

Is there a way to switch it to the top-right of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for that in the recent Cinnamon versions. Open "Cinnamon Settings", click on "Hot Corner" and choose "Top Right".

If you do not have this option, you need to update Cinnamon:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that, I've seen it before.  Thanks for the reminder!